# What is the best way to chain and filter DB queries in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

```
# A Post Model
class Post(models.Model):
    title = model.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    privacy = models.BooleanField() 

# query all post that have privacy = False, from a set of friends of type User.
# friends = [user1, user2, user5, user9]
def get_friend_posts(request):
    # Repeat the statement below for the size of friends. (4 here)
    friend_posts = Post.objects.filter(privacy=False).filter(user=fiends[0]) 
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'friend_posts' : friend_posts
    })
    return render_to_response('friends_page.html', variables)
```

1. What's the best and optimal way to do such a DB query ?
2. Also, how can I append query_set datatypes ? In my example I would need to run
   the query in a loop. (which I am currently not doing in the code)

EDIT/UPDATE:

```
posts_query = Posts.objects.filter(privacy=False)
for friend in friends:
    q_list.append(bmks_query.filter(user=friend))

for q in q_list:
    friend_posts += list(chain(q))
```

Is there a better way then this for my needs ?

Comment: For #2, I think I can use "chain" form "itertools" to add the querysets of the 4 friends.

Answer (score 2):

Django Querysets are lazy so they don't evaluate until you try to access the results. You can either chain the filters as your have done, or put them all in one. I guess it really depends on if you have all the information when you start or if you need to dynamically add the filters based on something. Either way, the end result of the query will be the same. Check out django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) on the subject

```
friends_posts = Post.objects.filter(privacy=False, user=friends[0])

friends_posts = Post.objects.filter(privacy=False).filter(user=friends[0])
```

for your second part. I think you just want a simple '__in' filter which will give you all the posts whose user is in the friends. ([django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in))

```
friends_posts = Post.objects.filter(privacy=False, user__in=friends)
```

Django by default will let you have 'friends' be a queryset itself and will execute a subquery when it is getting the results. If you don't want to execute a subquery, you can force your friends to a list and the it will query for the friends, then query for the posts.

```
friends_posts = Post.objects.filter(privacy=False, user__in=list(friends))
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I have added a new snipped of code to the orginal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for the ['__in' filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) - ie:

```
def friend_posts(request):
    template = 'friends_page.html'

    friends = get_friends(request.user) # Gives you [user1, user2, user3] etc
    friend_posts = Post.objects.filter(privacy=False, author__in=friends)

    context = {'friend_posts': friend_posts}

    return render_to_response(template, context, RequestContext(request))
```